# select the highest/greatest sum group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and I want to take the sum of the columns and get the result with the highest/greatest sum

this is my table

```
sales
+-------------+----------+--------------------------------+
| package_id  |  amount  |          datesales             |
+-------------+----------+--------------------------------+
|     123     |    100   |  2019-12-01 09:18:19.000000    |
|     123     |    100   |  2019-12-01 09:18:19.000000    |
|     123     |    100   |  2019-12-02 09:18:19.000000    |
|     123     |    200   |  2019-12-02 09:18:19.000000    |
+-------------+----------+--------------------------------+

datesales column is in timestamp
```

this is my query

```
SELECT max(AMOUNTSUM) AS amount42
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNTSUM
                        FROM sales
                        where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
                        date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
                        and package_id = 123
                        group by datesales
                    )
```

i have 4 entries and the dates are today and yesterday, so I was expecting to get highest/greatest sum based on the datesales column which is in timestamp

the datesales(today) has a sum of 200 while the datesales(yesterday) has 300,
I want to get the 300 result and I don't know what is wrong with my query

EXPECTED RESULT

```
+-----------+-------+
| yesterday |  300  |
+-----------+-------+
```

THE RESULT I GET

```
+-----------+-------+
| yesterday |  200  |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi Reve, Can you post the data with the timestamp because with the way you represented the data we can see why it is not working

Comment: @zip i updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Your query is kind fine, but just  `group by DATE(datesales)` Because at the moment it does not group at all ;-)

Comment: @Alex when I changed date(datesales) in the group by part, it returned an error

Comment: >Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the *date*, not the *date/time*.  You can also eliminate the subquery:

```
select sum(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNTSUM
from sales
where datesales < curdate() + interval 1 day and
      datesales >= curdate() - interval 6 day and
      package_id = 123
group by date(datesales)
order by amountsum desc
limit 1;
```

Note that I changed the date comparisons so they are index-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT MAX(v.amountsum) AS amount42
  FROM (
         SELECT DATE(s.datesales)  AS sales_dt
              , SUM(s.amount)      AS amountsum
           FROM sales s
          WHERE s.package_id   = 123
            AND s.datesales   >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL -6 DAY
            AND s.datesales    < CURDATE() + INTERVAL +1 DAY
          GROUP
             BY DATE(s.datesales)
       ) v
```

Comment: i entirely concur with Gordon Linoff, emphasizing here: reference *bare* column `datesales` in conditions in the WHERE clause; so the query is ripe for appropriate index; don't wrap the column in function (i.e. `DATE(salesdate)`)

Comment: Typo `ABD` should be `AND` I guess

Comment: yes @spencer7593 I understand. thank you I'm learning a lot. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Since you're grouping by the datesales, you don't need to SUM the amount, because the group by will SUM the amount anyways.

Remove the SUM(AMOUNT) and just select the amount.

```
 SELECT amount
 FROM sales
 where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
 date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day 
 and package_id = 123
 group by datesales
```

Comment: i get an array of data instead of just the highest sum(amount)

Comment: the result was 100 100 100 200 instead of 300